# Describing the subspace of a span of Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

$S = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix}2 & -1  \\ 0 & 0  \\  \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}   0 & 0  \\
    -1 & 1  \\
    \end{bmatrix}\right\}$.
The question is to describe the subspace spanned by $Span(S)$

What is the procedure to do this? Any guidance?

Comment: Did you look up the definition of span?

Comment: $\text{Span}(S)$ is already a subspace, so it does not span any subspace.

Comment: The span of vectors $u,v$ in a vector space $V$ is the subspace of $V$ which consists of all linear combinations $au+bv$ for $a,b$ in your ground field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, the space spanned by $S$ is the set of matrices of the form
$$
\left( 
\begin{matrix}
2\lambda & -\lambda \\
-\mu & \mu
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
for some coefficients $\lambda, \mu$ living in the field which your original vector space is over.

Answer (score 1):

Simply,  $\{s\cdot\begin{pmatrix}2&-1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}+t\cdot\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\-1&1\end{pmatrix}| s,t\in\mathbb F\} $ where $\mathbb F$ is the base field.  By definition.